# Full list of new tags in the JSF 2.0

Tags: java, jsf-2

Where to find the full list of all tags that are introduced in JSF 2.0? Yes, I could open the 1.2 and 2.0 references and compare the tags one by one, but maybe somebody did it before?

I know that the list includes:

```
h:body
h:button
h:head
h:link
h:outputScript
h:outputStylesheet
```

Something else?

**Update:** In addition to the JSF HTML tags mentioned above, the list also includes (according to the [JSF 2.0 Refcard](http://refcardz.dzone.com/refcardz/javaserver-faces-20)):

Core Tags:

```
f:ajax
f:event
f:validateBean
f:validateRequired
f:viewParam
f:metadata
```

Facelets Tags:

```
ui:component
ui:composition
ui:debug
ui:decorate
ui:define
ui:fragment
ui:include
ui:insert
ui:param
ui:remove
ui:repeat
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look at the [JSF 2.0 Refcard](http://refcardz.dzone.com/refcardz/javaserver-faces-20). It is a very good source for JSF in general, and all the JSF 2.0 tags are marked.

The only downside is that you have to provide your email and get the refcard sent there, instead of just downloading it.

Comment: The refcard is short and seems to be complete. It is exactly what I looked for. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Downvoted because link points to resource that can't be downloaded without creating account on the linked site...

Answer (score 6):

The best I've been able to find is [this Andy Schwartz weblog post](http://andyschwartz.wordpress.com/2009/07/31/whats-new-in-jsf-2/), but it's not exactly what you're looking for -- it's a wrapup of **everything** that's new in JSF 2.0.  There's a lot of detail about the new tags, but it's not in a single section, it's spread throughout the document.